# removing subset transactions form file

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have a file containing data as follows

```
10 20 30 40 70 
20 30 70 
30 40 10 20 
29 70 
80 90 20 30 40 
40 45 65 10 20 80 
45 65 20
```

I want to remove all subset transaction from this file.

output file should be like follows

```
10 20 30 40 70 
29 70 
80 90 20 30 40
40 45 65 10 20 80
```

Where records like

```
20 30 70 
30 40 10 20 
45 65 20
```

are removed because of they are subset of other records.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** easiest way is to use [std::set](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html)

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

...

std::set< int > s1, s2;

...

// Is s1 a subset of s2?
bool test = std::includes(s2.begin(),s2.end(),s1.begin(),s1.end());
```

You could create a set of sets, and then do a n^2 amount of include tests to remove the duplicates. Be sure to check which set is larger, to pick which one should be removed.

This is not the **fastest** way to do it, but probably the easiest.